# Fixed point of functional iterative root

Tags: functional-analysis

We say that a function $f:X \mapsto X$  is an n-th iterative root of function $F: X \mapsto X$ if it satisfies a functional equation
$$f^n(x)=F(x)$$ where $f^n(x)$ means n-th iterate of function $f$ i.e. $f^n(x)=f(f^{n-1}(x)); f^0(x)=id$.

My question is: Does continuity of function $F$ implies existance of fixed point of $F$?

Comment: Isn’t $F(x)$ arbitrarily chosen? Then why would it’s continuity imply existence of a fixed point?

Answer (score 0):

A function is continuous if preimages of open sets are open.

Let $X$ be a two element set with the discrete topology (where every subset of $X$ is open) then any function $f:X\rightarrow X$  is continuous. Label the two elements of $X$ as $a$ and $b$. Define $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$. Then $f$ is continuous but does not have a fixed point.

On the other hand, if $X$ is a convex compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow X$ has a fixed point. This latter result is called the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).